# multidimensional array loop

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array

```
return array(

// This level separates instances by their instance key.
'cytec' => array(

    // This level separates models by their model key.
    'model1' => array(

        'title'   => 'Business card model 1 title',
        'preview' => 'public path to preview image',
        'pdf'     => 'web safe path to PDF to generate from',
        'fields'  => array(

            'title' => array(
                'label'        => 'Title',
                'type'         => 'text',
                'required'     => true,
                'coordinate-x' => 30,
                'coordinate-y' => 20,
                'rules'        => 'required',
            ),

            'phone' => array(
                'label'        => 'Phone',
                'type'         => 'text',
                'help'         => 'syntax +32(0)3 485 85 53', 
                'coordinate-x' => 40,
                'coordinate-y' => 20,
                'rules'        => '',
            ),

            'position' => array(
                'label'        => 'Position',
                'type'         => 'select',
                'options'      => array(
                    'developer' => 'Web Developer',
                    'designer'  => 'Web Designer',
                ),
                'required'     => true,
                'coordinate-x' => 40,
                'coordinate-y' => 20,
                'rules'        => 'required|in:developer,designer',
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
);
```

and I get this returned

```
Array ( 
   [model1] => Array ( 
                  [title] => Business card model 1 title 
                  [preview] => public path to preview image 
                  [pdf] => web safe path to PDF to generate from 
                  [fields] => Array ( 
                                 [title] => Array ( 
                                              [label] => Title 
                                              [type] => text 
                                              [required] => 1 
                                              [coordinate-x] => 30 
                                              [coordinate-y] => 20 
                                              [rules] => required 
                                           )
                                 [phone] => Array ( 
                                              [label] => Phone 
                                              [type] => text 
                                              [help] => syntax +32(0)3 485 85 53 
                                              [coordinate-x] => 40 
                                              [coordinate-y] => 20 
                                              [rules] => 
                                           ) 
                                 [position] => Array ( 
                                                [label] => Position 
                                                [type] => select 
                                                [options] => Array ( 
                                                               [developer] => Web Developer
                                                               [designer] => Web Designer
                                                             ) 
                                                [required] => 1 
                                                [coordinate-x] => 40 
                                                [coordinate-y] => 20 
                                                [rules] => required|in:developer,designer 
                                              ) 
                             ) 
                )
  )
```

but now I wan't to loop through this and just get the name of array model1 back.
How do I do this? I don't need the values of the array model 1 just the name

Comment: Is `cytec` at level1 fixed... or it can change ..?

Comment: it's fixed everything is fixed

Comment: then whats the problem. see for my answer .. have I misunderstood anything or is this what you want .. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the keys out of an associative array, use the following structure:

```
foreach( $array as $key => $value )
{
     echo($key);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $array = 'your returned array'

 echo $requiredValue = $array['cytec']['model1']['title'];
```

more generically if you have associative array then you can use [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loop

```
foreach($array as $key=>$value)
{
   print_r($value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print_r($x['cytec']['model1']['title']);
```

Answer (score 0):

To get keys of an associative array you can also use:

```
while ($cytec_name = current($cytec)) {
   echo key($cytec).'<br />';
}
```